# Idea for fun "flair" on the top bar

Tags: feature-request

It would be cool if the score indicator at the top made a cute indication when it was a prime number.

Comment: That would be cool, but it sounds to me like a network-wide change, and a really random one at that. That said, looks like I'm two upvotes away from a prime right now, which I do find interesting.

Comment: What would be the purpose of this?

Comment: Same purpose as "hats".  Just to be fun.

Comment: There seems to be some debate as to whether 11303 is prime.  [this](http://www.numbersmath.com/is-prime/solved/is-11303-a-prime-number) says no, [this](http://www.2dtx.com/prime/prime11303.html) says yes.

Comment: I really wonder how can that be a debate. 11303 = 127*89, so it isn't prime.

Comment: Maybe it's a "creationism" site or Republican site. They have their own "alternative" math.

Comment: @JDługosz I think that may be an erroneous statement . . .

Comment: @JDługosz Last time I checked, liberals, progressives, and democrats were the ones pushing for common core. Where two plus two can equal five if you show your work.

Comment: I was thinking of videos and websites where they "proove" that the Earth can't be billions of years old with arithmetic errors (and anyone who points out the mistakes just gets banned).  I think one about the speed of the moon's recession gets oft repeated.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon looking at [this article](https://en.wikipedia/wiki/Common_Core_State_Standards_Initiative) I don't see anything about Common Core being graded funny.

Comment: May I point out that that is a Wikipedia article. Try these http://www.freedomworks.org/content/top-10-reasons-oppose-common-core - http://thefederalist.com/2014/09/24/top-ten-things-parents-hate-about-common-core/ -  http://www.utahnsagainstcommoncore.com Utah is also a kind of testing ground for common core, and frankly, I haven't learned anything new in my math class from eighth to tenth grade.

Comment: My brother, who is in third grade, came home with some supposed method to check his long division. My dad, who taught calculus for years, had no idea what he was doing. And my brother did it about five times and got different answers. To sum it up, common core is stupid and makes no sense. At the very least, something is seriously wrong with it. @JDługosz

Comment: I think people are simply saying "common core" to all the same teacher fails and bad textbooks we've had all along.  In '75 or so my gradeschool teachers had no comprehension of what was in the math lessons.  A few years later, I had a couple of bimbos for science teachers who were completely clueless and said many outright wrong things.  Nothing has changed: we don't spend what it takes to have enough and good teachers, and the school boards are filled with people undermining rather than promoting education.

Comment: As for not choosing the most trendy subject for my joke earlier, I should note that the page in question did not show its work or offer any explaination, so it can't get partial credit for trying.

Answer (score 6):

What you propose might be a neat gimmick, but compared to [the 12,772 other feature requests just on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[feature-request]%20-[status-completed]%20-[status-declined]%20duplicate%3a0%20is%3aq) that have yet to be either implemented or declined, I think it should have an exceedingly low priority.

I vote **no.** Even without having gone through that list of feature-requests on MSE, I can say with certainty that there are far more important things for the designers, developers and testers to spend time working on.